# How to change a innerHtml of an div in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React. I have 6 divs and whenever I call `foo()` I want to add a number to the first div that's empty.

For example, let's say that the values of the six divs are 1,2,0,0,0,0 and when I call `foo()`, I want to have 1,2,3,0,0,0.

**Here is what I've tried:**

```
var index = 1;

function foo() {
    let var x = document.getElementsByClassName("square") // square is the class of my div
    x[index-1].innerHTML = index.toString() 
    index++;
}
```

I don't know when I should call `foo()`, and I don't know how should I write `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

The "React way" is to think about this is:

1. What should the UI look like for the given data?
2. How to update the data?

Converting your problem description to this kind of thinking, we would start with an array with six values. For each of these values we are going to render a div:

```js
const data = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
  
function MyComponent() {  
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((value, i) => <div key={i}>{value}</div>)}
    </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Now that we can render the data, how are we going to change it? From your description it sounds like every time a function is called, you want change the first `0` value in the array to another value. This can easily be done with:

```
// Find the index of the first 0 value
const index = data.indexOf(0);
if (index > -1) {
  // if it exists, update the value
  data[index] = index + 1;
}
```

To make this work properly with React we have to do two things: Keep track of the updated data in state, so that React rerenders the component when it changes, and update the data in a way that creates a new array instead of mutating the existing array.

You are not explaining how/when the function is called, so I'm going to add a button that would trigger such a function. If the function is triggered differently then the component needs to be adjusted accordingly of course.

```js
function update(data) {
  const index = data.indexOf(0);
  if (index > -1) {
    data = Array.from(data); // create a copy of the array
    data[index] = index + 1;
    return data;
  }
  return data;
}
  
function MyComponent() {
  var [data, setData] = React.useState([0,0,0,0,0,0]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((value, i) => <div key={i}>{value}</div>)}
      <button onClick={() => setData(update(data))}>Update</button>
    </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use state to hold the value and then display the value of that variable.

If you're using functional components:

```
const App = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const foo = () => {
        const tempValues = [...values];
        tempValues[index] = index;
        setValues(tempValues);
        setIndex((index + 1) % values.length);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { values.map((value) => <div key={`square-${value}`}>{value}</div>) }
            <button onClick={ foo }>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In class-based components:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        index: 0 
    };

    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
}

foo() {
    const tempValues = [...values];
    const newIndex = index + 1;
    tempValues[newIndex] = newIndex;

    this.setState({
        values: tempValues,
        index: newIndex
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { values.map((value) => <div key={`square-${value}`>value</div>) }
            <button onClick={ this.foo}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: will  setValue() be my function and does this need to be inside of a class

Comment: @Mihai824HD I've updated my answer to show it either way

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the `innerHTML` of a React component, you can try this:

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={foo()} />;
```

the `foo()` here returns the value you want to post in the div.

But in my opinion, your way of thinking on this problem is wrong.

React is cool, but the logic is a bit different of common programming :D

Comment: You may want to include how OP would have to change `foo` to make it work with this approach.

Comment: Note the name `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` indicates a potential vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach would be to have the divs created by React (using its render method). Then you can pass a variable from array, which is stored in your state. You then just need to change this array within the state and it'll reflect in your view. If you need a working example, just let me know.

However, if you want to update the divs that are not created using react, then you need to use a dirty approach. I would suggest not to use react if you can't generate the view from react.

Answer (score 0):

React is good to separate the concerns between the view and the data.
So the concept of `state` for this example is useful to store the data. 
And the `JSX`, the React "template" language, to display the view.

I propose this [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-dawn-e0rl7):

```
import React from "react";

class Boxes extends React.Component {
  state = {
    divs: [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
  };

  add() {
    // get the index of the first element equals to the condition
    const index = this.state.divs.findIndex(elt => elt === 0);
    // clone the array (best practice)
    const newArray = [...this.state.divs];
    // splice, i.e. remove the element at index AND add the new character
    newArray.splice(index, 1, "X");

    // update the state
    // this is responsible, under the hood, to call the render method
    this.setState({ divs: newArray });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Boxes</h1>
        {/* iterate over the state.divs array */}
        {this.state.divs.map(function(elt, index) {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{ border: "1px solid gray", marginBottom: 10 }}
            >
              {elt}
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add a value</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Boxes;
```